# Meu select não se redimensiona ao tamanho da fonte. Como resolver?

Tags: html, css

Adicionei um `select` no meu `form`, porém quando coloco o tamanho da fonte de 35px o `select` não se ajusta ao tamanho da fonte, ocorrendo um corte.

Veja na imagem abaixo o que ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que o tamanho da fonte seja realmente de 35px, como resolver esta situação?

**HTML**

```
<figure class="cx-fotos-portugal">

    <form>
    <select>
        <option selected="selected">Escolha a cidade</option>
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    </form>

    <img src="./fotos-portugal/foto-portugal-capitania-do-porto-cascais.jpg">

</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
    figure.cx-fotos-portugal{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal form{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 550px;
}

figure.cx-fotos-portugal form select{
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b9bdc1; 
    color: #797979; 
}
```

Comment: O que seria esse `height: 20%;` no formulário?

Comment: vou atualizar meu código

Comment: Essa não é uma resposta válida para a pergunta feita.

Comment: Gladison, já apresentei diversas soluções pra você em algumas perguntas, que estranhamente nunca funcionam. Se você pegar o código que você disponibilizou e passar para um executável seja o próprio do Stack Overflow, ou um JSfiddle ou qualquer outro, verá que o select se adapta perfeitamente ao tamanho da fonte.

Comment: @Gladison agora seu código funciona. Simplesmente não faz sentido sua pergunta. O que está errado?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss A fonte do meu `seletc` permanece do mesmo jeito da imagem apresentada acima.

Comment: Não permanece, não. Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/acwoss/vur5vfyj/

Comment: @Bsalvo Amigo, agora funcionou! Mas eu tive que colocar `height: 70px;`. Compreendo e reconheço sua ajuda, mas quando posto que não funcionou estou sendo verdadeiro.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou, vocu editar para 70px mais a ideia é a mesma. A resposta é o height.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Deve ser herança de algum css que causa isso. Pois tive que colocar `height: 70px;` para dar certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque altura em seu select:

```
figure.cx-fotos-portugal form select{
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #b9bdc1; 
    color: #797979; 
    height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, continua do mesmo jeito.